# Installation of CUDA 9.0 in windows 10

Tags: python3, cuda

I am trying to install Cuda 9.0 in windows 10. for the purpose of running this example:
    https://github.com/andi611/Apriori-and-Eclat-Frequent-Itemset-Mining

Python Version: 3.6.5 ( Anaconda)

Operating System: Windows 10

Cuda Version: 9.0

The cuda software is installed properly but when I am running this line in python:

```
  import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
```

It's throwing the below error:

```
 Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pycuda\gpuarray.py", line 4, in 
 <module>
import pycuda.elementwise as elementwise
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pycuda\elementwise.py", line 35, in <module>
from pycuda.tools import context_dependent_memoize
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pycuda\tools.py", line 34, in <module>
import pycuda.driver as cuda
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pycuda\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
from pycuda._driver import *  # noqa

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

First I installed Cuda 10.0 that also did not work then I tried with cuda 9.0 and its showing the same error.

When I am trying to install pycuda old version:

```
 pip3 install pycuda==2018.1

 Error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```